# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option when trying to execute pl/sql using python

Tags: python, oracle, plsql, cx-oracle

AM trying to execute the PL/SQL script which am constructing at the run time but getting

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
```

Looks like some formatting issue with the script as it is showing as STRING but still not sure how to resolve it.

Below is the code that am trying:

```
script = '''Set serveroutput on;
    DECLARE
    V_req pls_integer;
    BEGIN
    V_req := infomediary_nse.request(
            p_inApp_id  => 100,
            p_inPayload => XMLTYPE(
       '<tag>hello</tag>'
      )
      );
      END;
      /'''

dbconnection = cx_Oracle.connect(ConnectionString)
str, err = dbconnection.cursor().execute(script)
```

Comment: Can you please post the entire script, or at least what `ConnectionString` contains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set serveroutput on
```

is not a PL/SQL command, but a [SQL*Plus](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/tuning-SQL-Plus.html#GUID-233D9103-017C-4832-B5E1-E38D32F9B00D) one, so you can only use it in SQL*PLus.

Even the final `/` should be removed, because it also is SQL*Plus specific.

This should work:

```
script = '''DECLARE
    V_req pls_integer;
    BEGIN
    V_req := infomediary_nse.request(
            p_inApp_id  => 100,
            p_inPayload => XMLTYPE(
       '<tag>hello</tag>'
      )
      );
      END;'''
```

If you used `set serveroutput on` to get the result from `DBMS_OUTPUT` calls, you can have a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/TerryMooreII/3773572).

For example, this:

```
import cx_Oracle
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(..., ..., ...)
c = conn.cursor()

vSql = '''begin
           dbms_output.put_line('Hello!');
          end;
'''
c.callproc("dbms_output.enable")
c.execute(vSql)

statusVar = c.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER)
lineVar = c.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)

while True:
  c.callproc("dbms_output.get_line", (lineVar, statusVar))
  if statusVar.getvalue() != 0:
    break
  print (lineVar.getvalue())

conn.close()
```

gives:

```
E:\Python>python testOracle.py
Hello!
```

Comment: Worked like a charm after removing the first line of script. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting same error while executing stored procedure from python and by removing `/` at the end fixed this issue in python.

The error message `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option` means that the Oracle database is not able to understand the PL/SQL statement that you are trying to execute. This can happen for a number of reasons, including:

- The PL/SQL statement is not syntactically correct.
- The PL/SQL statement is using a feature that is not supported by the Oracle database version that you are using.
- The PL/SQL statement is trying to access a table or other object that does not exist.

To fix this error, you need to check the PL/SQL statement for any syntax errors. You also need to make sure that the PL/SQL statement is using features that are supported by the Oracle database version that you are using. Finally, you need to make sure that the PL/SQL statement is trying to access a table or other object that does exist.

Here are some tips for troubleshooting this error:

- Use a PL/SQL editor to check the syntax of your PL/SQL statement.
- Look for errors in the PL/SQL statement, such as missing semicolons or misspelled keywords.
- Make sure that the PL/SQL statement is using features that are supported by the Oracle database version that you are using.
- Check the Oracle documentation for information on the features that are supported by each Oracle database version.
- Make sure that the PL/SQL statement is trying to access a table or other object that does exist.
- Check the Oracle database to make sure that the table or other object exists.

Comment: Open a new question or see duplicate questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72533233/how-can-i-get-the-dbms-output-in-python  (But read the [Using DBMS_OUTPUT](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/plsql_execution.html#using-dbms-output) documentation first).  And upgrade cx_Oracle, see [python-oracledb](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).